# How can I bind a key-sequence ending in `C-h`?

Tags: key-bindings, keymap

Evil-mode binds <kbd>C-w</kbd><kbd>h</kbd> to evil-window-left. I'd like to bind <kbd>C-w</kbd><kbd>C-h</kbd> to the same so it will work whether or not I lift my finger off the Control key in time. But <kbd>C-h</kbd> is the help key. Is there any reasonable workaround for this?

I'm willing to lose the Help functions on <kbd>C-h</kbd> since I can access them elsewhere, like <kbd>F1</kbd>.

*Update*: I may have found the solution.

```
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "\C-w\C-h" 'evil-window-left)
```

This seems to work without affecting <kbd>C-h</kbd> behavior in other cases.

Comment: You can post your own answer, and you can accept it. If you are not interested in doing that or in obtaining other answers, consider deleting your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be simpler than I expected:

```
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "\C-w\C-h" 'evil-window-left)
```

It clobbers the help key, but only in this key-map and only following a <kbd>C-w</kbd>.